# Wear OS emulator not properly responding

Tags: android, android-emulator, wear-os

I am developing a Wear OS app. Now for my graduation presentation I would like to record the screen of the emulator to demo the app. But the problem is that my emulator is stuck at this screen.
[image: Screen it's mostly stuck at]

Sometimes the changes and the volume buttons work, but the rest is completely stuck. At that point is doesn't seem to receive 'touch' input.I also have a square emulator that works fine, but I am personally not a big fan of the square look.

I tried the following:

- Restart emulator (also cold boot)
- Wipe emulator
- Completely delete emulator folder and reinstall
- Restart computer

Comment: If the emulator doesn't respond to touch input it might be in ambient mode. Try clicking the power button on the emulator control and see if it wakes up. The emulator behaves in the same way as a real device in that it will automatically enter ambient mode after a brief time of inactivity (~5 seconds). If that still doesn't work maybe just try to create a new round emulator?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I updated the emulator to the latest version. It works now.